# Uploadify IIS onAllComplete

Tags: php, iis, uploadify

I am using uploadify for a project and i found this issues the onAllComplete or onComplete will not work when the script is put on a server with IIS6 and IIS7 with PHP.

works fine on two different servers running apache and PHP (with different versions)

```
    'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) { 
        top.location='./dashboard.php?page=success'
    },
```

Tested in IE9, FF11, and Chrome. all do the same as said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, It was a setting on the server can not remember what one though.